# Помогите с задачей JS

Tags: javascript

Реализовать класс, описывающий новость (заголовок, текст,
массив тегов, дата публикации). В классе необходимо реализовать
один метод print, который выводит всю информацию в таком
виде, как на рисунке 1.
Обратите внимание на то, как выводится дата:

---если с даты публикации прошло менее дня, то выводится
«сегодня»;

---если с даты публикации прошло менее недели, то выводится «N дней назад»;

---в остальных случаях, полная дата в формате «дд.мм.гггг».

Рисунок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваши попытки?..

Comment: @Павел похоже, что попытка представлена в ответах.

Answer (score 0):

```
class infoNews {
  constructor (heading, text, arrayTags,date ) {
    this.heading=heading
    this.text=text
    this.arrayTags=arrayTags
    this.date=date

  }
  getDate(){    
       let today = new Date(),          
       yesterday = today.getDate() -1,           
       roomLastMessageDate = new Date(dateTime);           
   if (dateTime) {
       if (today == roomLastMessageDate) {                                                                
           return 'Сегодня'                                                                                
       } else if (yesterday == roomLastMessageDate) {                                                     
           return 'Вчера'                                                                                  
       } else {                                                                                            
           return roomLastMessageDate;     
  }
}
  }
  conclusion(){
      document.write(`< style="font-size:20px${this.heading}  font-size:10px${this.getDate} font-size:15px${this.text}  font-size:10px${this.arrayTags}`)
    }
    
  }


 let foo= new infoNews ('НОВОСТЬ ДНЯ ', 'Вы также можете сделать это, чтобы получить дату на сегодня, завтра и вчера. ... Начиная с 2.10.5 moment поддерживает указание форматов вывода календаря для', '#lorem #lorem #lorem' )
foo.conclusion(infoNews)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите